# Upload failed for 'image.jpg'

Tags: assets

I tried to upload an image in the backend, but I always get the error: `Upload failed for 'image.jpg'`. In the logs is this:

`[16-Jul-2015 21:33:48 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4966029 bytes) in /var/www/virtual/conwave/html/service/cgk/craft/app/vendor/imagine/imagine/lib/Imagine/Image/Metadata/ExifMetadataReader.php on line 72`

Can anybody help me? I have no idea what the problem is.

Thanks!

Comment: Check your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files for `[error]` and see if anything useful is being logged.

Comment: Also, make sure you have the correct permissions set for that directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running out of PHP memory as it's processes the image when it's uploaded. The fix for this is to increase the memory limit, which you normally need to get your hosting company to do for you. Try 512mb.

Comment: Great :) I had the same issue on a client site a couple of weeks ago.